# Flutter Blue why found just gdevice beacon but not found my devices

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I want my application to be able to find bluetooth devices which it can only find. gDevice-beacon But it can't find my device.

[it's found gDevice-beacon but not found my devices]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/teouc.png)

```dart
Widget deviceName(ScanResult r) {
    String name = '';
    if (r.device.name.isNotEmpty) {
      name = r.device.name;
    } else if (r.advertisementData.localName.isNotEmpty) {
      name = r.advertisementData.localName;
    } else {
      name = 'N/A';
    }
    return Text(name);
  
  }
  void onTap(ScanResult r) {
    print('${r.device.name}');
  }
  Widget listItem(ScanResult r) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: () => onTap(r),
      leading: leading(r),
      title: deviceName(r),
      subtitle: deviceMacAddress(r),
      trailing: deviceSignal(r),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Which kind of device is your device? Is it advertising?

Comment: It's a Bluetooth speaker

Comment: Yeah that might be the problem. Bluetooth speaker usually use Bluetooth Classic for music streaming. Flutter Blue is a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) library. These two are not compatible. What do you want to connect to the speaker to? Just for streaming?

Comment: I just wanted it to be able to connect. So Which one do I need?

Comment: I'm unaware of any way to connect to a Bluetooth classic device using flutter. Maybe just connect to it using the android settings? Every sound you play in your app afterwards should be played on the speaker